# Init nuxt plugins once instead of server + client

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using [nuxt i18n](https://github.com/nuxt-community/nuxt-i18n) and [@nuxtjs/router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/router), which I initialize with async data from my API whenever the user loads the app.

Router example:

```
export async function createRouter() {
  const routes = await httpService.get('routes')

  return new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: routes.data
  })
}
```

This works fine. However, both plugins are initialized twice, first from the server, then from the client, which I noticed because of 2 api calls foreach plugin when I load the app.

Why are plugins initialized twice in `univerval` mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended and important for the plugins to actually work!

Both sides, `server-side` and `client-side` (in the browser), are independent and have to initialize plugins again as they aren't shared in any manner.

Comment: Allright, I was expecting the server side initialization to be reused. Thanks for clarifying